# jQuery: How to make divs move down. Waypoints and Z-index

Tags: javascript, css, z-index, parallax, jquery-waypoints

So I am trying to make elements 'fall' from under a div that is at a higher `z-index` called `fallingfruit_header`. If possible, I would like the `fallingfruit` divs to scroll at different speeds and then stop at the footer.

My main problem is that I have various parallax elements and I'm finding it hard to work with the scroll, particularly scroll that triggers divs to move downwards with the scroll. I have tried using `position: fixed;` but it is on a `position: relative` div so it doesn't work. In fact, right now I can't get the falling div to even show!

Any help, advice or direction to sources that might help would be fantastic. I am using waypoints.js to trigger scrolling events and if possible it would be great to continue using it . I am also using sticky.js for the sticky navbar.

So just to clarify, I'm looking to have divs fall to the footer triggered by scrolling that goes above the `#parallax_content` but under the `navbar` `#parallax_content` and `about-section`

[My CodePen so far](https://codepen.io/cigarette_unicorn/pen/vKqkkE)

## EDIT:

[Similar to this](http://codepen.io/rglazebrook/pen/ZYLQbK) but controlled by scrolling, not generated by jQuery like this example. This is just showing the motion I am looking to achieve.

## EDIT 2:

I have reworked the code and now have the divs I like 'fall' from behind the green div. However, I was hoping they would fall at different speeds according to the scroll, NOT automated like the snow effect. The reworked code is the same as above.

Comment: Just to clarify you want the header div to remain static or do you want it to scroll along with the two other divs until you reach the footer?

Comment: Which header? The `parallax_header` gets scrolled over by the rest of the content then the `navbar` sticks and the `fallingfruit_header` and everything else scrolls underneath the sticky navbar

Comment: this like animation banner

Comment: No not the banner, its elements that come from behind the banner. They are hidden using the z-index and then scroll down as the user scrolls. They are separate elements to the banner. The banner just hids them until they begin to scroll

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE using pure **CSS**

**CSS**

```
   .fallingfruit_header {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #6b92b9;
    background-image: url('http://pre11.deviantart.net/cbce/th/pre/i/2013/064/7/3/raindrops_simple_vector_by_lktronikamui-d5x2tp7.png');
    -webkit-animation: snow 20s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: snow 20s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: snow 20s linear infinite;
    animation: snow 20s linear infinite;
    padding: 200px 0;

}
```

**JS**

```
function wheel(event) {
      var delta = 0;
      if (event.wheelDelta) {(delta = event.wheelDelta / 120);}
      else if (event.detail) {(delta = -event.detail / 3);}

      handle(delta);
      if (event.preventDefault) {(event.preventDefault());}
      event.returnValue = false;
  }

  function handle(delta) {
      var time = 1000;
      var distance = 300;

      $('html, body').stop().animate({
          scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() - (distance * delta)
      }, time );
  }

if (window.addEventListener) {window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);}
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;
```

scroll event with a different speed.

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VjoEwz)

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question. I want to have divs move from under the `fallingfruit_header` with the scroll until you get to the footer. Not simply scroll from the header to the footer. Kind of like this but controlled by the scroll and from divs, not generated by jquery: http://codepen.io/valentin/pen/tLiyc

Comment: ohh so u want the  background effect go down like that only the banner?.

Comment: If you look at my code you will see divs called `fallingfruit_1` `fallingfruit_3`  and `fallingfruit_3` these are the elements I want to have falling from under the `fallingfruit_header` div and then stop falling when they reach the footer or the end of the `parallax body` div

Comment: yep i get it now :D

Comment: Great! :) Any ideas of how to approach it??

Comment: Getting there! I was looking to control it by the scroll though, not automatically generated. That was just an example of the motion I was looking for.

Comment: I don't know how to track the position based off of the scroll. Plus, I just realised you made it the banner. I wanted it to be over the background of the `parallax_body` on a higher `z-index` but it comes out from behind a separate, banner div called `fallingfruit_header` I think you're still confused by what I am asking..

Comment: Okay i will make another one.

Comment: This is how I solved the issue. The red dots now fall with the scroll: http://codepen.io/cigarette_unicorn/pen/vKqkkE

Comment: Haha, it's no problem. I actually want it to scroll at different speeds but I can not solve it. If you can help with that it would be wonderful!

Comment: Check my demo this is how to firing the scroll event

Comment: But this is on the whole page? I want it just on the fallingfruit elements. Like this but with the elements moving down, not up https://codepen.io/JTParrett/pen/BkDie